# Where can I rent 90's sports cars in Japan?

Tags: japan, car-rentals, automobiles, kanto

*Disclaimer: I am not advocating or planning on breaking any traffic laws, lots of fun can be had within these limits.*

---

As an [Initial D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_D) fan, I would like to do a roadtrip to the various mountain passes featured in the manga and anime series, which are [mostly located around the Kanto region.](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=153PxthPw54PXnUqDnjPftdrrpV8&hl=en_US)

[image]

I already went to a few passes using a rented Suzuki Swift, but it's power and handling are less than stellar, hence why I'm looking for more "fun" vehicles.

**Where can I rent 90's sports cars in Japan?**

I would like to rent a car for about a week. Price is not much of a problem.

(I don't want to specify an age limit, but any answer that allows a 22 year old to rent cars gets my thanks.)

*Note: by "90's sports cars", I mean Japanese cars like the [Nissan R-32 GTR](http://roa.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/14/49/980x551/547e4237f3451_-_gm9a7910.jpg), [Mazda RX-7 FD](http://wallpapercave.com/wp/JC1AOOq.jpg) (or [FC](http://stancewords.stanceworks.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/FC-RX7-gold-slammed-title.jpg)), [Honda NSX](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RZrvbnh6JDw/maxresdefault.jpg), [Toyota MR2](https://markdormangarage.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/p1090644.jpg) or [Toyota AE86](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Toyota_Corolla_GT_AE86_Trueno_hatchback.jpg/1024px-Toyota_Corolla_GT_AE86_Trueno_hatchback.jpg), etc.*

Comment: Found the current GT-R//

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try an exotics rental agency, like [Omoshiro Rent-A-Car](https://www.omoren.com/?lang=en), *omoshiroi* being Japanese for "interesting".  For example, their Chiba (Narita Airport) outlet has a [bunch of interesting cars](https://www.omoren.com/vehicle/index.php?transactionid=a15365b1b7b34c3bb7ddf76b7269a87fb7c81976&mode=search&category_id=&maker_id=&mission_type=&pref=12&search.x=37&search.y=9) on offer, including a Toyota AE86, Nissan Skyline GT-R, Toyota MR-S, Toyota 86G, etc.  (Note: there are multiple pages of listings, click on the little "次へ>>" to go to the next page.)  The listings do not include model years, and obviously most of their cars are much newer than the 90's, but they do have a number of vintage options as well.  Prices start from around ¥10,000/day.

Answer (score 7):

On the other side of Tokyo, near Hakone and Mt. Fuji, there is [Fun2Drive](http://fun2drive.co.jp/) which has a nice chart showing make/models available, along with [recommended touring routes](http://fun2drive.co.jp/recommendation/). Prices range from 5000-12000 yen for the first 90 minutes, depending on the [car and duration](http://fun2drive.co.jp/cars/)